# Checking for individual matching elements in two different array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have these two arrays

`arr1 = ["dog", "cat", "bird"]`

`arr2 = ["fish", "bear", "bird"]`

Notice how the only matching element is "bird" from the two arrays. I want to find a check that will say if any elements are matching return true.

For example this does not work `arr1.include?(arr2)` but looking for method that will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a good way to do this:

```
(arr1 & arr2).any?
```

`&` is a logic operator, if some elements exist in both arrays, this will return these elements.

`any?` checks if any elements exist in the array. If there exists at least one, then it return `true`.

Comment: What do `&` and `any?` do?

Comment: `&` is logic operator, if something element exist in two arrays, this return it. 

`any?` checking  something element exist in array, if at least one, it return true

Comment: Thanks @BartekGladys. My point was that this information should be included in your neat solution to make it more complete:)

Answer (score 1):

```
arr1.any? { |item| arr2.include?(item) }
```

This will check if any item from first array is included in the second array.

Answer (score 1):

You do this with intersection between two arrays and after this we can check if there are any matching elements in result.

```
(arr1 & arr2).present?
```

In your case we have

```
arr1 = ["dog", "cat", "bird"]

arr2 = ["fish", "bear", "bird"]
```

Result can be like this:

```
(arr1 & arr2).present?
```

It will return `['bird']`, so its not empty and the present? will return true.

Comment: Which version of Ruby has the `present?` method included in the `Array` class?

Comment: no method error, because `present?` is not included in Array class

Comment: We have it in rails. We can do [1,2].present? which will return true.

Comment: @BIlalKhan nice, +1. Under the hood is it exactly the same as `any?`